# JS Regex to allow only numbers, semicolon and hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I am building an application which should accept strings only with the following formats:

1. 12345 (only a number)
2. 12345;23456 (two or more numbers separated by ;)
3. 12345-12367 (a range of numbers separated by a -)

The java script regex should allow only the above formats & shouldn't accept any other formats or symbols . Can anyone come up with a regex for this?

Comment: You aren't going to be able to use a regular expression to guarantee the last one is a valid range.

Comment: If you're utilizing a semicolon as a delimiter between fields, maybe you should `split` the string and check if each element matches the other two conditions.

Comment: The first two are simple: `/^(\d+)(;\d+)?$/`

Comment: @Michael I would like to check for hyphen between both the numbers using javascript. I have other checks to see if its a valid range.

Comment: @Packwolf Then either of the already posted ansers will do the job.

Comment: @arxanas I am using split to check for the semi colon..but 12345/12367 is also being accepted. So, I wanted a regex to reject all the other symbols between both the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the RegExp that you need: `/^\d+((;\d+)*|-\d+)?$/`

`(;\d+)*` will check for multiple numbers separated by ";"

`-\d+` will check for a range

Comment: No need to escape the hyphen if it's the first or last character in a character class I guess.

Comment: Same here `=]` just commenting as some people prefer the code "cleaner" (with less unnecessary escaping).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^[0-9]+([;-][0-9]+)?$
```

That should work

`[0-9]+` matches 1 or more digits
[;-] matches a `;` or a `-`

`(...)?` is an optional match

`^` anchors the start and `$` anchors the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

**^[0-9-;]{0,50}$**

**0-9** only accept numbers

**-;** allow only  - and ;

{0,50} allow only 50 chars

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number portions you are looking for are 5 digits each time, the following should match what you want.

```
[0-9]{5}((;|-)[0-9]{5}){0,1}
```

If you need different lengths, you can update the {5} with either another fixed length or a range such as {3,5} for a string of 3 to 5 digits.  If you want to be able to capture more than two numbers with the speperators listed, you can use

```
[0-9]{5}((;|-)[0-9]{5})*
```